# Can the Command spell force someone to answer a question in a Zone of Truth?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mind-control

If you have an enemy in a Zone of Truth who failed their save, they can still choose to not answer. If a player casts Command on them with the word being "answer" would that force the creature to answer the question posed? Similarly, what if you cast the command "lie" on a creature in a Zone of Truth?

Comment: At least related: [Can I use the Suggestion spell to force a creature to tell the truth?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70695), [What spells or magic items are available to detect lies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172630)

Answer (score 6):

#### The *command* spell is almost entirely left to the GM

The [*command*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) spell states:

> [...] Some typical commands and their effects follow. You might issue a command other than one described here. If you do so, the GM determines how the target behaves. If the target can't follow your command, the spell ends. [...]

Notably, "Answer" is not in the given list of commands and so anything that happens from this command is going to be up to the GM.

But even if it *does* force somebody to answer a question, and they are required to tell the truth, they can still choose the talk around the question or give an answer that is unclear. In fact, a GM could even argue "Dog" is an acceptable *answer* to a yes or no question because it is *some* kind of answer, just not a particularly helpful one.

Comment: Is "Confess" a valid command?

Comment: Side note: This also covers the command "lie" mentioned in the question's text. The target currently can't lie, so the command ends immediately.

Comment: @Egor Alternatively, the lie is not deliberate, so *zone of truth* doesn't actually stop it. Alternatively alternatively, they just speak a lie they did not even know was a lie, and thus it also wasn't deliberately lying because they had assumed it was the truth but the spell just *knew* it wasn't, somehow

Comment: @Verdan I am now imagining Jim Carrey in The Mask, confessing to a host of things that don't matter and making a mockery of your first level spell.